# 5510 asa adblock

Tags: cisco-asa

Is there a way to block all ads using a 5510 ASA firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to block all hosts found in the list at http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/ though some times this can screw up certain sites and it is a lot of hosts that need to be blocked.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The only real way to do this on an ASA is by setting up regex's and applying them through service policies. That'd be a lot of regex's to check if you want to block all ads. If there are particular ones that you'd like to block, then you might be able to do it this way. Otherwise, you'll have to look into a different solution. A lot of content filters will do this for you. Look at Websense and McAfee SmartFilter. Both of those products integrate well with the ASA. I'm not 100% sure that they have an ad block option though.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Untangle (www.untangle.com).  For free, you get basic web filtering.  It doesn't "integrate" with the ASA per se.  However, you can setup an Untangle system as a "bump in the wire" without re-numbering your network.

In my experience, run Untangle on larger hardware than they recommend.